# How to find if an SQL job is configured on which database of that SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, jobs

We have a situation where we need to get a report of which jobs are created to run queries on which databases in one of our SQL Server?

Appreciating your response.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983)

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this table: msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps

Comment: Thank you. I got it